# On click the page isn't loading more content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm playing with web development and I can't seem to get my load button to work. I was able to hide the elements; however, I was unable to show them when the load button is pressed

HTML:

```html
<div class="portfolio_area">
  <div class="portfolio_wrap" <div class=" single_gallery">
    <div class="box-hidden">
      <div class="thumb">
        <img src="images/mm_mockups/Edges3.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="gallery_hover">
        <div class="hover_inner">
          <span>Mobile App</span>
          <a href="work_details.html">
            <h3>Ubar Mobile App</h3>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- </div> -->
<div class="more_works text-center">
  <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.portfolio_area .portfolio_wrap .single_gallery .box-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```js
$(function () {

    $(".box-hidden").slice(0,6). show();

    $("#loadmore").on('click', function(e){

        e.prventDefault();

        $(".box-hidden:hidden").slice(0,3).slideDown();
        if ($(".box-hidden:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }

        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });
});
```

I believe the problem is within my JS.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo. `$("#loadmore").on('click', function(e){` should be `$("#loadMore").on('click', function(e){` You want `loadMore` not `loadmore`

Comment: and he has misspelled prventDefault :(

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Good catch

Comment: @Anta You're partially correct. Those are not the only problems, but they are definitely problems that must be fixed for this to work. I also see that you are missing a ">" to close the opening div tag here: `<div class="portfolio_wrap" <div class=" single_gallery">`. Do you see it? Right after where you define the class "portfolio wrap". And you reference an element with an ID of "load" here `$("#load").fadeOut('slow');` but there is nothing with an ID of "load". Please elaborate on what this is supposed to do. I put it in CodePen and could not get it to do anything even after these fixes.

Comment: There is a ">" in my code. That was a copy and paste error. Also, I'm just trying to load more content onto my page E.x more cards when you press the load more button on my page. I followed this youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zC46LQ2gA0